# Unable to import data from csv file to mysql workbench on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import data from csv file to mysql table using mysql workbench Import/Export wizard to update my table. But The Import option is available only for certain tables while it is not available for some tables though both the tables belonging to same Database with same user privilege access.

I am using mysql workbench version 5.5.49, I just wanted to know why Import option is available for specific tables not for all belonging to same database. Please refer image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html

See "Table Data Import Wizard"

Whenever you import from CSV, make sure you select new table. Consider this as temp table. Then you can move data to your required table using insert from table or insert ignore from table

Answer (score 0):

The import option from csv is only available on windows. For linux there are several plugins that would do the trick